# How to send data from single form to multiple database tables using Hibernate, Spring MVC

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am able to send html form data to database using hibernate.  I am using mySQL 5.5, Hibernate, Java 1.6, Spring 3.0.  But I would like to send that same data to multiple tables in the database.  My issue is that I want to use only single html form not multiple html form.

I have these tables: name, address, email, login, phone_num.  From this one html form I want data to go to different tables. I want to do it using Hibernate so that I am not manually taking form data and inserting it in the database.

My understanding is that Hibernate is an ORM, which means that form data is mapped to given table. Is it possible for form data to be mapped to more than one table? I am not really concern that I use only one form although I said it in my original post.  What I would like to do is to have data from single form to go to more than one table.

My workaround solution is to create form per database table.  That way database table is mapped to a single form.  An another option is to collect input from form(s) and use Setters for the table object to insert the values and save that object to the database table.

Please let me know if this is possible.

Comment: The question is `I want to map some entity into several tables`. The fact that the data comes from HTML is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mapping object for each class (a new `Entity`).

Create a new object for each entity, and copy the data retrieved from the form in such objects.